# Help with proving this combinatorial identity?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

so I'm currently in a combinatorics course, and I am struggling immensely with proofs, especially with combinatorial identities. I have the following identity I am trying to prove:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{m} (-1)^k {n \choose k} =  (-1)^m {n-1 \choose m} $$

I tried to prove this algebraically by expanding the LHS and the RHS but it ended up being messy, so I gave up on that. In terms of a combinatorial proof, I have no clue what this identity is trying to say.

Any guidance towards both a combinatorial proof and an algebraic proof would be appreciated!

Comment: It can be done straight-forward"ly" with induction, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177421/proving-these-binomical-sums)

Answer (score 0):

if $k\ge 1, {n\choose k} = {n-1\choose k-1} + {n-1\choose k}.$  If you need to prove this then do so, but it may be that you already have.  It drives Pascal's triangle.

Making that change above

${n\choose 0} + \sum_\limits{k=1}^{m} (-1)^k ({n-1\choose k-1} + {n-1\choose k})$

Expanding that out, we will get something that telescopes.

${n\choose 0} - {n\choose 0} - {n\choose 1} +  {n\choose 1} +  {n\choose 2} - {n\choose 2} - {n\choose 3} + \cdots $

And all the terms except the last one will cancel each other out.